# stdout, stdin and stderr representation on AIX 7.1

Tags: bash, aix, proc, stdout

I've been porting a bunch of scripts on *AIX 7.1*. I got no prior experience with this Unix system.

The scripts were ran under `/bin/sh` and relied on `/dev/stdout`, `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stderr`. These files are known to be non-standardized and the *AIX 7.1* does not seem to implement them.

As I discovered the `/proc` VFS is present, so I tried to substitute the `/dev/std{in|out|err}` with `/proc/$$/fd/{0|1|2}`. This failed, since the descriptors are not links to a `pts` but a real char file devices with permissions *000* (`c---------`).

The `/bin/bash` is known to emulate many devices in `/dev` including `/dev/std*`. My limited experiments with switching to `/bin/bash` from `/bin/sh` and using `/dev/std*` were successful. However, switching & testing all the scripts to `/bin/bash` would be time consuming.

---

Question:

How to handle the standard IO files in *AIX 7.1* under `/bin/sh`? Is employing eg. `/dev/tty` the way?

// Example of a call in one of the scripts to be ported:

```
# param_protocol parameter apparently needs a file representation of the stdout
black_box_binary param1=$value1 param2=$value2 param_protocol=/dev/stdout
```

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297019/117549

Comment: I would clarify that "standard IO" could mean "(POSIX)-defined standard" or "stdio, such as stdin, stdout, stderr". As https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36448/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417996/117549 point out, POSIX has defined only certain I/O targets.

Comment: @JeffSchaller By "standard IO" I mean any "pseudo device file" which could be used as a redirect and passed as a function parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace those files by reading from `<&0` and writing to `>&1` and `>&2`, ie. stdin, stdout and stderr respectively.

Comment: It seems my scripts use eg. the `/dev/stdout` as a parameter to a function. Thus not only redirects. This doesn't work as a function parameter, does it?

Comment: Can you provide an example? (in your question)

Comment: What does black_box_binary do with its third parameter?

Comment: It seems it prints its protocol/log to the file specified by the parameter. So normally it should output the protocol to the standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Could the files `/dev/std{in,out,err}` be just symlinks to `/proc/$$/fd/{0,1,2}`? See "[Standard error and other output redirection](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/HT_standerr_output_redir.htm)" for background information. However, according a former thread here, the [Portability of “> /dev/stdout”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36403/) seems to be shell dependent.

Comment: No, on *AIX 7.1* they are not symlinks. I can tell this seems to be common on Linux or cygwin, but not on AIX.